# How to select another piece of data in a record returned by a max() command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, max

thanks for taking the time to help me out! I'm trying to make SQL do something that I imagine is easy for anybody who knows SQL, but I'm beating my head against at this point.

I have me a little table like this -

```
Update   Order    UpdateDate                OrderDate
9297    3590    2012-12-06                    2012-12-06 
9298    3590    2012-12-06                    2012-12-06 
9356    3590    2012-12-07                    2012-12-06 
9369    3590    2012-12-08                    2012-12-06 
9381    3590    2012-12-10                    2012-12-06
```

My goal is to find orders that have not been updated in the last 3 days.

The ugly version of what I'm trying to do is something like this -

```
Select order from orderstable
where cast(max(updatedate)-getdate() as int) >3
```

The goal here is to have the command return "orders" that have not been updated in the last 3 days. My current problem is I don't know how to make SQL focus on just the "most recent" updatedate for the order.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking for orders that have not been updated in the last three days? Or for orders that have not been updated within three of the order date? Your text indicates it's the first, your query effort shows it's the second.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to find orders that have not been updated within the past 3 days you are correct that my sample text thus looks wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just a date comparison:

```
select *
from orderstable ot
where datediff(day, updatedate, getdate()) > 3
```

I see, you have multiple records for each order and you want orders that have no update in the past three days.  I would do this with an aggregation:

```
select order
from orderstable ot
group by order
having min(datediff(day, updatedate, getdate())) > 3
```

You can also do it by looking for orders that don't have updates in the last three days:

```
select distinct order
from orderstable
where order not in (select order
                    from orderstable
                    where datediff(day, updatedate, getdate()) <= 3)
```

Comment: sorry, my example was a bit off...I've fixed it now. The problem I'm having at the moment is that my query will return order 3590 because it sees that todays date minus the date in the first record is greater than 3. I am trying to get it to only use the "most recent" updatedate when doing the maths.

Comment: +1, and your aggregation version's `having` condition could also be rewritten like this: `having datediff(day, max(updatedate), getdate()) > 3` (might seem slightly more straightforward to some, although I wouldn't insist).

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd avoid using DATEDIFF as it is not sargable: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/03/07/Low-Hanging-Fruit-of-Sargable-Expressions.aspx

```
    ;WITH MaxOrders AS (
        SELECT Order, MAX(UpdateDate) MaxUpdateDate
        FROM orderstable
        GROUP BY Order

    )

    SELECT Order 
    FROM MaxOrders
    WHERE MaxUpdateDate < DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE());
```

In this example, DATEADD is sargable because there is a static value ,GETDATE(), in the function. If the function had column values in it, it would not be sargable. In other words, if you were to change it to this:

```
WHERE DATEADD(day,3,MaxUpdateDate) < GETDATE();
```

it would no longer be sargable, as all column values would have to be evaluated in the function before a criteria match is determined. This is the problem with using DATEDIFF in the where clause. It has column values in the function. This is going to be very expensive on big data sets.

Comment: thanks for this information, I'd never heard about Sargable before and it was a very interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use getdate() to get the current date?

So something like this:

```
SELECT order FROM orderstable
WHERE datediff(day, updatedate, getdate()) > 3
```

(Yes, this does not answer the question asked in the title - but it does answer the problem posed in the body of the question)

To answer the question asked in the title, how about:

```
SELECT order FROM orderstable
WHERE datediff(day, orderdate, (select max(updatedate) from orderstable)) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
[Update] INT,
[Order] INT,
UpdateDate DATE,
OrderDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(9297,3590,'2012-12-06','2012-12-06'),
(9298,3590,'2012-12-06','2012-12-06'),
(9356,3590,'2012-12-07','2012-12-06'),
(9369,3590,'2012-12-08','2012-12-06'), 
(9381,3590,'2012-12-10','2012-12-06'),
(9382,3591,'2012-12-07','2012-12-06'),
(9383,3591,'2012-12-08','2012-12-06'),
(9384,3592,'2012-12-07','2012-12-06'),
(9385,3592,'2012-12-09','2012-12-06'),
(9386,3593,'2012-12-05','2012-12-06'),
(9387,3593,'2012-12-07','2012-12-06')    


--Assuming we don't care about time, cast to DATE to remove time values from GETDATE() function.
--It also assumes that today is inclusive.
;WITH RECENT_UPDATES_CTE
AS (
    SELECT [Order],MAX([UpdateDate]) [LastUpdateDate] FROM @T
    GROUP BY [Order]
)
SELECT DISTINCT T.[Order] FROM @T T
LEFT JOIN RECENT_UPDATES_CTE C ON C.[Order] = T.[Order]
WHERE C.LastUpdateDate <= DATEADD(DAY,-3,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: This one should work, but it seems needlessly complicated. You don't need to select distinct `Order` values from the original dataset (`@T`), as you've already eliminated the duplicates in `RECENT_UPDATES_CTE`, so just read `Order` from there without involving `@T` any more. Also note that using a left join's right side's column in a WHERE clause like that effectively turns your outer join into an inner join, because any NULLs, if ever possible, get eliminated in `=`, `<`, `<=` etc. comparisons (the point being, it is potentially confusing to use LEFT JOIN when it doesn't really work as such).

Answer (score 0):

Use OVER clause for finding MAX(UpdateDate)

```
;WITH cte AS
 (       
  SELECT *,
         DATEDIFF(d, MAX(UpdateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order]), GETDATE()) AS diff_date
  FROM orderstable
  )
  SELECT [Update], [Order], UpdateDate, OrderDate
  FROM cte
  WHERE diff_date > 3
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71b2d/1/0)